# Get contours of the terrain from file with libgdal

Tags: c++, gdal

I'm trying to convert a GeoTIFF image to GEOJson data using C++ and `libgdal` library.

I can do this like this:

`gdal_contour -i <shift> -snodata 32767 -f "GeoJSON" -a height <input.file> <output.file>`

And [the documentation](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_contour.html) says:

> Functionality of this utility can be done from C with [`GDALContourGenerate()`](https://gdal.org/api/gdal_alg.html#_CPPv419GDALContourGenerate15GDALRasterBandHddiPdidPvii16GDALProgressFuncPv).

This function has quite a clear set of parameters, except for two:
`GDALRasterBandH hBand` and `void *hLayer`. As far as I understand, this is actually input and output. However, I can't figure out how I can initialize both objects.

I tried to do like this:

```
OGRLayerH *lr = new OGRLayerH;
if (GDALContourGenerate(GDALOpen("/file/path.tif", GA_ReadOnly), 10, 0, 0, nullptr, false, 0, lr, -1, -1, nullptr, nullptr) == CE_None)
{
    printf("success");
}
else
{
    printf("fail");
}
```

But I think I made some blunders. Could you suggest please?

Answer (score 0):

You need to read band from image file. `nBandIn` is integer value with band number. Then you can use `hBand` in your code. Also dont forget to call `GDALAllRegister();` ro be able to read file

```cpp
GDALDatasetH hSrcDS = GDALOpen("/file/path.tif", GA_ReadOnly);
    if( hSrcDS == nullptr )
        exit( 2 );

    GDALRasterBandH hBand = GDALGetRasterBand( hSrcDS, nBandIn );
    if( hBand == nullptr )
    {
        CPLError( CE_Failure, CPLE_AppDefined,
                  "Band %d does not exist on dataset.",
                  nBandIn );
        exit(2);
    }
```